# Publish data from a LAN webapp to a public site

Tags: mysql, tomcat, web-applications, struts2, tomcat6

I have a struts 2 webapp. IT works very well and currently is only accessible to the office LAN. The client would like to be able to publish some of the data in the database to a public website. I would like to hear some ideas on how to do this.

My setup is tomcat 6 and using MYSQL as the DB.

I was thinking of creating a php website and having an almost duplicate DB on the public webserver. Perhaps I could create an XML string and fire it at the public site. Which would then have a php page parse the XML and put it in the public DB.

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make a service call from the public site to the internal site? Why would you duplicate anything?

Comment: Does your public site is allowed an access to the db?

Comment: the main app is behind the firewall. So it would be better to publish the data from this side to the www server. I could open the ports in their network to allow incoming connections but I feel they wont want this.